# Does low_search_collection_id work in conditionals?

Tags: low-search

I've been trying the following without luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Search Form:

```
> {exp:low_search:form query="{segment_3}" result_page="search/results"}
> <input type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Search a word...">  
> <select class="form-control" name="collection" id="collection">
>     <option value="" selected="selected">Show results from</option>
>     <option value="1">Collection 1</span>)</option>
>     <option value="2">Collection 2</option>   </select>   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
> {/exp:low_search:form}
```

Results page:

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" limit="50" orderby="date" sort="desc"}
{if low_search_collection_id == "1"}
<p>show this</p>
{if:else}
<p>show this</p>
{/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should definitely work for keyword searches.

If it doesn't, check if the variable actually generates output, along with any other `{low_search_x}` variables. If that doesn't generate output, then there could be an extension conflict. Disable all extensions, *except* Low Search and try again. If that solves the problem, one of the other extensions isn't checking for `ee()->extensions->last_call` and/or not returning the correct value in the `channel_entries_query_result` hook.

If the above doesn't help, submit a support request here: https://getsatisfaction.com/low

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Yes, the variable generates output fine. I tried a couple of them. The issue is that I need to use them in conditionals which is failing.